# Perl console : basic commands and fe_sendauth : no password was not working

Tags: postgresql, perl, sqitch

I am currently working on the sqitch , to run scripts automatically for postgress sql , i had seen few posts talking about the .pgpass file , i had placed my .pgpass file in my root directory and , but when i run my sqitch deploy command , it says password not found , please check my commands below.

i am using the strawberry perl console , and i am also not able to execute basic commands like vi editor , ls etc.. please provide some assistance on this.

found perl recomended from sqitch website : http://strawberryperl.com/

commanmd :

```
sqitch --engine pg deploy db:pg://mypostgress.connqa9taxeg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbone
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the *"Strawberry Perl console"*? I have never heard of such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL documentation says this

> On Microsoft Windows the file is named %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf (where %APPDATA% refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile).

You need to put your `.pgpass` file in the correct place